# All partitions in Hard Disk are not displaying while Kubuntu and Ubuntu installations

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10, kubuntu, ubuntu-13.10

Currently my system runs on Windows 8 Pro. I want to install either Ubuntu or Kubuntu alongside Windows. I have Ubuntu 10.10, 13.04, 13.10 and Kubuntu 9.10 disks. I would like to install Kubuntu than Ubuntu. I tried to install all disks at different times. Whenever I reach the page of installation to choose the drive to install the OS, not all the drives in my computer is shown. Only the C drive is shown properly. Besides it there are 2 more drives in my computer. It is shown as a single drive. So I logged into my Windows 8 again and created a new drive. Then I tried to install the OS again and the same problem is still there. How can I solve it ?

[image: This is the screenshot of my disk partitions in Windows]

Comment: You don't create a drive, you create a partition. I guess there's only one drive in you pc. Make a screenshot of the partition manager in windows please.

Comment: @davidbaumann How to make screenshot of the partition manager ?

Comment: So there's only one drive... how should Ubuntu detect 3?

Comment: @davidbaumann ok...how can I install my Linux OS then ? Which drive should I choose ?

Comment: @davidbaumann What i meant by drive is actually the partitions. Why not the 3 partitions are displaying ?

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of the installer?

Comment: @TomJ - The reason the installer can't see the other paritions is because they are NTFS which isn't supported by every linux distrubution. If you want to create a new partition, use the linux tool of your choice ( through the use of a live bootable disk ), to make it unallocated space.

Comment: I had the same issue when tried to install Ubuntu on my Windows 8 system. I searched in askUbuntu and they told me that it will be Windows 8 blocking the installation of Ubuntu along it. I felt thats true. So I took the risk of installing Ubuntu by formatting the hard disk and I done  it successfully. But what happened later was that I was unable to boot Windows at all. If you don't want Windows, you can take the risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue when tried to install Ubuntu on my Windows 8 system. I searched in askUbuntu and they told me that it will be Windows 8 blocking the installation of Ubuntu along it. I felt thats true. So I took the risk of installing Ubuntu by formatting the hard disk and I done  it successfully. But what happened later was that I was unable to boot Windows at all. If you don't want Windows, you can take the risk.